# scala json serialization missing fields (json4s)

Tags: json, scala, serialization, json4s, lift-json

I am using json4s to serialize some scala map objects.

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

val m: scala.collection.Map[String, Map[String, StatCounter]] = Map("key" -> Map("secondKey" -> StatCounter()))

implicit val format = DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.write

println(m)
println(write(m))
```

Correct result would be:

```
Map(key -> Map(secondKey -> (count: 0, mean: 0,000000, stdev: NaN, max: -Infinity, min: Infinity)))
```

strangely I get only for the serialized class

```
{"key":{"secondKey":{}}}
res1: Unit = ()
```

How to get it serialize correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out json4s was lacking the correct serializer. Maybe it would be better to be notified via an exception?

Anyway: adding

```
+ FieldSerializer[StatCounter]()
```

to the `DefaultFormats` fixes the problem